# Toggling off all settings in python and julia to get bare setup

Tags: spacemacs, python, lsp

since recently I am using LSP for python, tex and julia on macos with spacemacs develop.
To some extend this is great, but it is something awefully slow using a gui... and it seems that it is not only LSP.

So in these times it would be great to toggle off all additional python/julia 'add-ons' and just keep the basic keybindings and e.g. just the syntax highlighting for python/julia.

I was thinking about using an enhance fundamental-mode with font-locking for the mentioned modes.

Do you have a hint how to achieve this? Or is there maybe a better way to get a fast emacs in gui... in a terminal the navigation is quite fast even with all fancy settings turned on.

Maybe there is a special mode like tiny-python or something similar...

Thank you in advance!
Fab

Answer (score 0):

You can switch off the gui parts by customizing variables `lsp-ui-*` as described [here](https://develop.spacemacs.org/layers/+tools/lsp/README.html#variables).
For python-mode you can use non-lsp based backend, the anaconda-mode

```
(python :variables python-backend 'anaconda)
```

see [here](https://develop.spacemacs.org/layers/+lang/python/README.html).

The same for julia: if lsp layer is installed, all languages get lsp backend by default, unless it is specified to be another backend or e.g. `nil`.

Further, you can see, which modes are activated using `C-h m` and
switch them off as well.
Mode activations e.g. autocompletion are happening in the mode hooks, i.e. you can remove
some functions in `python-mode-hook` etc.

Comment: Excuse me for answering so late... thank you very much! And to turn the individual features off and on I could  bind a defun to a keybinding where I adjust the settings, I assume... btw, I did install gccemacs which improved the situation